# Firebase AdMob not working

Tags: android, admob

I am a new Android Studio developer. I have made 2 apps with AdMob before, but now I made new app with ads, but they not going through. I have also tried with blank app, but the problem persists.

Here is the code below:

[image: Picture]

First this in `MainActivity`, the color is red and cannot resolve appear.

When I generate app, this occurred:

[image: PICTURE]

I have checked my code 5 times.

Please help me to resolve this.

This is in `activity_main`:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: How are you importing the AdMob SDK?